# How to merge a new partition with the existing root partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using virtual box for Ubuntu. my earlier partition  `sda1`filled up so i increased the space and now I have another partition, however i still receive low disk space errors so i want to merge this device `sda2` to the root partition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this from a Live ISO. First turn off the VM, then go to Settings > Storage and attach the ISO from the left pane. Then if needed, change the boot order to keep CD boot first.

Now boot from Live ISO and select Try ubuntu. Then open GParted. Now we will going to resize Root partition.

First delete the Partition 2 that is going to be merged. If anything is in it, Then backup it.

Now we need to turn off swap partition. First execute `sudo swapoff -a` from terminal. Then comment out (Add `#`) before UUID lines of swap partition. Then in GParted right click linux-swap and click Swapoff.

Now delete the swap partition. Now resize the root partition and merge the unallocated space from partition 2. Keep some space to get the Swap back.

Re create swap, uncomment lines from /etc/fstab and update grub and initramfs `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`.